# Is it possible to avoid remounting components if query params or route params change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some page filter like sortBy, groupId etc which needs be in the URL as the user may come to the filtered view from other pages. I tried keeping it in both router params and query params but the issue is that whenever these params change in the url the entire component is being re-mounted. Is there any way to avoid this or a better way to handle filters on a listing page.

```
// users main container
<Switch>
    <Route
        path={`${this.props.match.url}/users/:sort_by/:group_id`}
        component={UsersListContainer}
    />
</Switch>
```

usersListContainer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class UsersListConainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getStats();
        this.props.getUsers();
     }
     .......
     ........

     render() {
        const { usersData, userStats } = this.props;

        return (
            <>
                <Stats data={userStats} />
                <Table data={usersData} />
            </>
        );
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { usersData, userStats } = state.users;
    return {
        usersData,
        userStats
    };
 };

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UsersListConainer);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected since your path changes anytime you sort or group your users list differently. However, you don't really want unique pages for this.

I would just use URL query params for the sorting and grouping. That won't require a component rerender. So change your your route to be:

```
<Route
    path={`${this.props.match.url}/users`}
    component={UsersListContainer}
/>
```

This will only cause a rerender whenever the `props.match.url` changes.

---

As for the grouping and sorting, just use the URL API. These are parameters that shouldn't be part of your route:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
```

To read and query the correct data, you can then parse these when your component mounts before data fetching:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const sortBy = url.searchParams.get('sortBy');
const groupBy = url.searchParams.get('groupBy');
```

If you want to change the ordering or grouping, simply write the new query parameters to the URL so that they persist after refresh. You can do this programatically (in an onClick handler, for example):

```
url.searchParams.set('sortBy', 'foo');
url.searchParams.append('groupBy', 'bar');
window.location.search = url;
// retrigger fetch here
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I am using HashRouter in my application. I tried your code as `const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
        params.set('sortBy', 'foo');` But this doesn't update the URL. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @ShivratnaKumar I edited the code (last snippet), forgot to apply the changes :)